# Skip characters or extract substring from string variable in batch for comparison?

Tags: batch-file, comparison, substring, filenames, skip

I'm trying to do a line by line comparison of 2 .txt files. But the problem is for the first file I'd like to start comparing line by line after the first 9 characters of each line of the first 10 lines in the 1st file with the second file. I read somewhere that you can extract substring, but I've only seen format where you have to specify the length of the substring (~start,length), for mine each line has a different length. How do I accomplish this?

```
 < !logPath! (
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%refLogPath%) DO (
      set logLine=
      set /p logLine=
      set refLogLine=%%A
      echo !logLine!
      echo !refLogLine! 

      REM check logLine against refLogLine(ENG-REF.log)
  REM skip 1st 9 chars of each line
      if NOT !logLine!==!refLogLine! (

     set flag=false
         echo !logLine!
 ) else (
 set flag=true
  echo !flag!
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should look into using something other than batch to do this type of processing.

But if you really want to proceed...

Have a look at the HELP documentation for the SET command. Type `HELP SET` or `SET /?` from a command prompt.

Within the documentation you will see that you can omit the length argument, meaning take from the starting position to the end of the string: `!logline:~9!` will give what you want. Remember that the positions start with 0.